# New Line in Apex Variable

Tags: visualforce, apex-variable

I am trying the following code:

```
<apex:variable var="variable1"  value="{!CASE(object.field,

                    "val1",  "line1
                              line2",
                    "val2",  "line1
                              line2",
                    "val3",  "line1
                              line2",
                    "")}" />
```

Can I print line 1 and line2 on separate lines ?

Comment: try with \n ....

Comment: tried <br/> and \n as well. The text is just printed with the text followed by the tag. Tried escape = "false" as well. It is not supported with apex:variable

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with below code and it is working fine

`<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:variable var="variable1"  value="{!CASE(Account.Name,
                                               'val1',  'line1<br/>
                              line2',
                                               'val2',  'line3<br/>
                              line4',
                                               'val3',  'line5<br/>
                              line6',
                    '')}" />
        <apex:outputText value="{!variable1}" escape="false"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>`

Answer (score -1):

Just use a `<br/>` where you want the new line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/59075)

Comment: What do you mean? It is the solution of the problem, he wants to add a new line, so if he adds <br /> the new line is added at this place.